# changing a pointer to method class using method class

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl

I wanted to change the value of a pointer to class method by using a class method, but it doesnt work. This is the code:

TestCode class

```
class TestCode {
public:
  TestCode() {};
  virtual ~TestCode() {};
  void render1() { (rendering code) }
  void render2() { (rendering code) }
  void event1(SDL_Event* e, void (TestCode::* point)()) {
      if (e->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_t) { point = &TestCode::render2; }
  }
};
```

main file

```
int main(int argc, char* args[]) {

   TestCode t1;
   void (TestCode::* tptr1)(SDL_Event*, void (TestCode::*)()) = &TestCode::event1;
   void (TestCode::* tptr2)() = &TestCode::render1;

   while (!end) {
       while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev)) {
           if (ev.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_t) { tptr2 = &TestCode::render2; } //-> works
           (t1.*tptr1)(&ev, tptr2); // -> doesnt work
       }
       (t1.*tptr2)();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only thing that `event1()` will change is its own parameter. That will accomplish absolutely nothing at all, whatsoever.

Comment: `void (TestCode::* point)()` takes the pointer by value, so `point = &TestCode::render2;` updates a copy and the calling function is none-the-wiser. Pass the pointer by reference and you can change where the pointer points for everybody.

Comment: I think that in order to change the value of the pointer passed in by the caller, `event1()` is going to need to take a reference to a function pointer, rather than a function pointer. This code needs `typedef`s to be half-way readable, I think

Comment: Or `std::function` if that's compatible with the API.

Comment: Uncle Bob quote: `do you have pointers to function ... C++ programmers do, but they do not use them if they sane`. https://youtu.be/zHiWqnTWsn4?t=2888

Comment: Sanity is relative. My second cousin in this case.

Comment: Maybe real question should be: what are you trying to achieve? What functionality you want to provide that you think pointers to methods are best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account the answers, i had to pass the pointer by reference. I have altered the event1 method and the tptr1 pointer. The rest is the same. It now works. Like i said, im still learning C++ and SDL.

event1

```
void event1(SDL_Event* e, void (TestCode::*& point)()) {
    if (e->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_t) { point = &TestCode::render2;  }
}
```

tptr1

```
void (TestCode::* tptr1)(SDL_Event*, void (TestCode::*&)()) = &TestCode::event1;
```